# Create an Electron/React Local Application which can open a local JSON FIle - Edit it and export it

Tags: reactjs, json, electron

I'm new in React and trying to create an Application which can open a local JSON File with a list of elements like this in a dialouge:

```
{
    "autor": "Name",
    "selftext": "Text",
    "title": "Title",
    "date": "2019-11-18 18:36:40",
    "content": "Content",
    "link": "www.web.com", 
    "origin": "web.com",
    "filename": "XY",
    "id": 1
},
```

The imported JSON should be expandable and editable and after that export it with the changes.
Here I need some help with guidance where to start and what I need for that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the file on the frontend, you will need to:

- Construct a `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` with an `<input name='json' type='file' required>`

Then create a callback, `handleSubmit`, that extracts and parses the chosen file:

```
function handleSubmit(e: Event) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the form from refreshing the page
    const formData = new FormData(e.target); // parses the data into a map
    const file = formdata.get("json");
    const filereader = new FileReader();
    filereader.readAsText(file);
    filereader.onload = () => handleResult(filereader.result);
}

function handleResult(result: string|ArrayBuffer|null) {
    if (result) {
        // Handle the file as you would like here. You will likely need to
        // parse the file here w/ JSON.parse. You could cache it
        // or pass it to the React.Context API so that it is available through  
        // the application.
    }
}
```

To write/export the file on the frontend, you can push the JSON object into a `Blob` and temporarily construct an `<a>` element to initiate the download:

```
function save() {
  const json = // retrieve JSON from wherever you stored it
  const file = new Blob([json], {endings: 'native'});
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download='config.cfg'
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.click();
}
```

Granted because the process might be slightly different because of Electron, but that is how it would work with React in the Browser.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and well explained answer! With this I can solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's great, it's a good idea to mark it as the answer if it works for you so it will help others in the future 